# Possible to iterate over two union arrays with flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a function `foo` that takes a union of two arrays, and the only thing it does is loop over the array, but with this I get flowtype errors, that some properties are missing in the array. Is it not possible to do this? I'm not using any properties at all. They are both arrays, so flow should know that they are iterable.

[A live example in the flow editor](https://flow.org/try/#0FAFwngDgpgBAEgQwHYBMA2sC8MDeAfYGGAagQCcQBLAYwwEkUAuGAZxDMqQHMAaQk8NGYByABbJ0UYXyKlq1KCxYB7DouYBBMmQRgAPGw7cAfDJIRlLSlWVI6SAGbLmhzr2B4AvgG5goSLAAMlBcMNj4-KQUNPRMrOxuZsSCUCIYXNIePn4pMACiSFTgYfASGDB4MMFcvsAOAK5I1DZIME7KABRQhdaU6jBaOvqIqBjGFQPaunrVxgCUuPzdRX0sAHROZHkI1KIdHQuY4ziec8CeQA)

```
type Handle = {|
  +articleId: string,
  +type: 'handle',
  +accessories: Array<string>,
  +positionInfo: string,
|};

type Leg = {|
  +articleId: string,
  +type: 'leg',
|};

type Entity = Handle | Leg;

function foo(entities: Array<Handle> | Array<Leg>) {
  entities.forEach(() => {})
}
```

Comment: Put a check whether property available or not. But when you are using it Iterates over every entity of the array which creates the error.

Comment: But I'm not using any properties at all?

Comment: but entities.forEach(() => {})  trying access the same properties in the both of the arrays.

Comment: Looks like a bug..

Comment: but it's not accessing any properties at all @UllasHunka 
If the Array type is an interface, then all things that are an array should be possible to interate over, right?

Comment: You should type it like this:

[Flow try](https://flow.org/try/#0FAFwngDgpgBAEgQwHYBMA2sC8MDeAfYGGAagQCcQBLAYwwEkUAuGAZxDMqQHMAaQk8NGYByABbJ0UYXyKlq1KCxYB7DouYBBMmQRgAPGw7cAfDJIRlLSlWVI6SAGbLmhzr2B4AvgG5goSLAAMlBcMNj4-KQUNPRMrOxuZsSCUCIYXNIePn4pMACiSFTgYTBaOvqIqBgweDDBXMa+wNS2bDBQhdaU6vmdxdgA2jj85FS0UAwirtyZRCki4lVSZgjyiipqLMwDwiCKINIwu-vCALpmFlY2do7OR9MZfJ48uCPR45P3CTNm80fpmU8pyaLSQbUWkgKRW6W16RTAJSGbzGsSm30e-D+YgkGFmMFWCiUqhh22ObEOZIO534ly6tnsTjRRgxQJBrRAMHSUK6PW5-RgSKIoxiEziwgeeKxAKewL8DgArkhqNcYE5lAAKDrQ3l9MAASleRC1PJYADonGQ8qtROr1QbMMZcJ49cBPHLlBrjVRFHrfGr1RCMHyYb7gP6uX0Q94gA)

Answer (score 2):

You can type the array as containing `Entity` objects (e.g. `Array<Entity>`), which you can later refine. Alternatively, you could type the input as `Array<Handle | Leg>`, but since you already have the `Entity` type defined, we should use that.

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAEghgOwCYBtoF4oG8BQUqiQBcUA5ABaKoSkA0eUcATsAJYDGaAkkiQM7AmrBAHN6+OO3YQ+fAPZCZJAIJMmcEAB4BQ0QD5xUMHL6s2chFwQAzOf0HCxOAL44chaABkIIqJlz4HiSkaCJ0DMxsnBA89rpOru7g0ACiCGygfrBUaFAAPlDeIgDcbtYArgjs5ghQtnIAFBDpZqxKUKrqWmkZIHoAlNgMzRltfAB0tkwpkuRNLZnoekP4+AD0ax3ABOSsfEZywsC0dShyAO5QANYIF-vAlNty5UxQAAYjZiBvUABuzKw4AAjNAMdabCBmcgQV7sCzAODCfZwbLIXIKRiFHxQBrWJhyAC2O2gwLkvwgYKgGygSAg1mErQsUDk1mJ7x6Xx+HnGUAA6tB2IgoOU+CTKdSmHThBACSMCHI6qwRC9oM9tudduxyMyENAzFA9kQGABIVis+a9cYePzoTAhHykQYBVb4OEIATYDwnSIcbhIZxZT6gSmuizyNDjM4iBoAImUUFCMZOXsYLF9MSQg0pAYgKFFBvNQZAVuSNrtlDRNCdIagbo9WBTPuiPBOxlMNSstgDmCLNbrcgjUdj8Yr1CTBGS3rTzaQrZMjMsNjkWZdObz0GdLup-NrQog5NqcFkMO2Dzg6oFZJhECQjBQKAOslYIIpLvBu9F+yBIEYx7Toh2c82Q+BZvj+OAUHKaBKD4GtqVuKBJQJREEEcYVUKZQVP0YZADXuaFJSmaAZTAYM3xxIsSBI0AV1WVx8GcfoXDcOttiDMYUgADzgAkwFyTAAG0GCwJs-WCEE4HIOgJ2IMhQlIZxDBE6cxLIYA5DkYBpKCMhRzQaTJGkWQFDGEgBIAXTndtWAsTs7DIIFmAUnBzLKDSLVaGQuJ4viIH6IA))

```
// I made these types writeable and non-exact since it
// doesn't seem to matter for the sake of this question.
// You can make them read-only and exact in your code if
// you want (and I personally would unless I had good
// reason not to).

type Handle = {
  type: 'handle',
  articleId: string,
  accessories: Array<string>,
  positionInfo: string,
}

type Leg = {
  type: 'leg',
  articleId: string,
}

type Entity = Handle | Leg;

function foo(entities: Array<Entity>) {
  entities.forEach(entity => {
    // At this point, flow knows that our `entity` variable
    // either contains a Handle or a Leg (from the above
    // definition of the `Entity` type.) We can use a
    // refinement to figure out which one it is:
    if (entity.type === 'leg') {
      const {type, articleId} = entity
      console.log("A leg", type, articleId) 
    } else if (entity.type === 'handle') {
      const {type, articleId, positionInfo} = entity
      console.log("A handle", type, articleId, positionInfo) 
    } else {
      // We can even assert that we covered all possible
      // cases by asserting that the `entity` value has
      // no remaining union cases and is therefore empty
      (entity: empty) 
    }
  })
}

const entitiesExample = [
  {articleId: 'blah', type: 'leg'},
  {articleId: 'toot', type: 'handle', accessories: [], positionInfo: 'bar'}
]

foo(entitiesExample)
```

*Sidenote: I noticed flow had trouble refining the types if I used `==` check on the `type` property instead of the above `===`. If anyone has any idea what's going on there, I'd love to know, since my intuition is that `==` should work fine.*

Comment: Sounds like workaround and doesn't answer why iterating over `entities: Array<Handle> | Array<Leg>` is not allowed

Comment: @Aleksey, flow doesn't treat a `Array<Handle> | Array<Leg>` as equivalent to `Array<Handle | Leg>` when running a foreach. Perhaps it should.

Comment: No, I don't think it should be treated as `Array<Handle | Leg>`, but it definitely should be `Array<T>`